# Parar hilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos

A modo resumen actualmente el resultado que me da es:

```
Miembro_X esta mirando el canal ...
Miembro_X esta mirando el canal ...
Miembro_X esta mirando el canal ...
Ja nadie mira la tv.
```

Código:

CLASE CASA:

```
public class Casa {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Comandament c = new Comandament();
        int numMembres = 5; //total familia

        UnitatFamiliar[] membre = new UnitatFamiliar[numMembres];
            for(int i=0; i<numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i] = new UnitatFamiliar(c);
            membre[i].setName("Miembro_"+i);
            membre[i].start();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i].join();
        }

        System.out.println("Nadie mira la tv");
    }
}
```

CLASE UNIDADEFAMILIA

```
public class UnitatFamiliar extends Thread {
    Comandament comandament;
    static int canal;
    public UnitatFamiliar(Comandament c) {
        comandament = c;
        canal = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        comandament.Agafa();
        int canal = (int) ((Math.random() * 100) + 1); 
        System.out.println(getName() + " esta mirando el canal " + canal);
        //Mirar la tele
        try {

            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!!");
        }
        //Dejaa el mando
        comandament.Deixa();
    }
}
```

A partir de aquí, sale la nueva clase que es:

COMANDAMENT, con dos métodos `Agafa()` y `Deixa()`:

```
public class Comandament {

    private boolean avalible = false;

    Comandament() {}

    void Agafa() {
        while (avalible == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        avalible = false;
        notify();
    }

    void Deixa() {}
}
```

Necesito que los usuarios cuando cojan el `comandament` `"mando de la tv"`, solo ellos puedan cogerlo durante X tiempo (en este caso ya esta implantado `Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);`  en la clase `UnitatFamiliar`.

Es decir que cuando otro mire el mismo canal, no dirá nada el programa, pero cuando cambie de canal tiene que avisar.

Estoy bastante perdida. ¿Podéis ayudarme?

Comment: `en este caso ya esta implantado Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);`. No, no lo está. Pones el *thread* a dormir pero cualquier otro *thread* puede coger el mando. La pregunta es bastante amplia y no veo como arreglarla sin escribir el programa yo (que no es lo que toca); baste decir que estás tratando con **concurrencia** y **secciones críticas** y que necesitas echar un vistazo a como funciona esto en Java; en particular el *keyword* `synchronized`.

Comment: El programa seguro que tiene errores. Busco una solución a el programa para conseguir que solo una persona pueda coger el mando. Si crees que está todo incorrecto puedes modificar las partes. Necesito ejemplos y no los encuentro :(

Comment: Tienes que hacer lo que te ha dicho @SJuan76, la palabra synchronized es clave para lo que quieres hacer o lock o semáforos, pero tendrás que echarle un ojo tu para que veas lo que es y como se trabaja con ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que ibas encaminada. Por partes:

### Main: Casa

En el main inicializas 5 threads y a todos les pasas el mismo objeto `Comandament` que corresponde al recurso unico compartido que los threads compiten por obtener.

```
        Comandament c = new Comandament();
        int numMembres = 5; //total familia

        UnitatFamiliar[] membre = new UnitatFamiliar[numMembres];
        for (int i = 0; i < numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i] = new UnitatFamiliar(c);
            membre[i].setName("Miembro_" + i);
            membre[i].start();
        }
```

Luego, correctamente esperas que todos los threads finalicen junto al thread principal, haciendoles `join()`

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i].join();
        }

        System.out.println("Nadie mira la tv");
```

### Threads: UnitatFamiliar

En cada thread, utilizas un metodo para solicitar la esclusividad del recurso comandament:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    comandament.Agafa();
```

Luego realizas la logica una vez esta el recurso obtenido.

```
    int canal = (int) ((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    System.out.println(getName() + " esta mirando el canal " + canal);
    //Mirar la tele
    try {

        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!!!");
    }
```

Y por ultimo liberas el recurso

```
    //Dejaa el mando
    comandament.Deixa();
}
```

### Recurso compartido: Comandament

Dado el codigo anterior, se requiere que comandament implemente 2 metodos:

1. `Agafa()`: Debe bloquear el thread y obtener el recurso de forma exclusiva para quien lo llame, solo retornar una vez el recurso de obtiene
2. `Deixa()`: Debe liberar el recurso

La forma de implementar lo anterior es haciendo uso de un [lock](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cierre_de_exclusi%C3%B3n_mutua), permitiendo que solo un thread a la vez tenga dicho *lock*.

Comenzando con tu implementacion original:

```
public class Comandament {
    private boolean avalible = false;

    Comandament() {}

    void Agafa() {
        while (avalible == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        avalible = false;
        notify();
    }

    void Deixa() {}
}
```

El primer error, es que el control comienza no disponible, cuando el estado original deberia ser disponible:

```
private boolean avalible = true;
```

El segundo error, es que en el metodo `Agafa()` no estas obtiendo ningun *lock* y ademas estas invocando `wait()` y `notify()` sin poseer el [lock intrinseco](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) del objeto actual. Una forma de realizar esto, es simplemente hacer el metodo completo `synchronized`:

```
synchronized void Agafa() {
    while (avalible == false) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    avalible = false;
    notify();
}
```

Y con eso ya esta cumpliendo con lo que se le pide al metodo, solo 1 thread puede obtener el recurso, y bloquea la ejecucion mientras el thread actual no pueda obtenerlo.

Por ultimo, obviamente el 3er error es que no hay ninguna implementacion para liberar el recurso. Solo basta con dejar el recurso disponible y notificar a los demas threads:

```
synchronized void Deixa() {
    avalible = true;
    notify();
}
```

Y listo, eso era lo que te faltaba, ya pueden mirar la TV:

```
Miembro_0 esta mirando el canal 95
Miembro_1 esta mirando el canal 62
Miembro_3 esta mirando el canal 62
Miembro_2 esta mirando el canal 32
Miembro_4 esta mirando el canal 60
Nadie mira la tv
```

Comment: te agradezco mas que el resultado el tiempo que te has tomado en comentar cada cosa. Solo puedo decirte : GRACIAS GRACIAS Y GRACIAIS